# iOS PageViewController how to handle scrollview of child

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have an `UIViewController` A, The view A has a `UIPageViewController`, from A I added some `UIViewControllers` B C as chid of `UIPageViewController`.
In B, I have an `UITableView`. 
In C, I have an `UIScrollView`
In A, I implemented `UIScrollViewDelegate`

I used that codes bellow to handle scroll events of B and C from A

```
    for (UIView* view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        [(UIScrollView*)view setDelegate:self];
       }
    }
```

It worked with C but didn't work with B.

I thought `UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView` so I can't handle it from other view. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (UIView* view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
   if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
      UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)view;
      tableView.delegate = self;
   }
   else if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
      UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
      scrollView.delegate = self;
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you but still not work, can't use - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView